# How to define kanbanboard states in OpenERP 7.0?

Tags: odoo, kanban

I've got my kanban view working, but there are no states. Items created are shown in kanbanboard.

Where can I define where to find states? Is it in model or in view?

Can't find anything usefull from google and there is no mention in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you should refer the kanban view of opportunity and project task. State is a field to be defined in object it self.